# Insert data into mysql table by clicking on a link using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, mysql

I`m new in PHP and I'm creating a Airbnb website with recommendations for users. I have three tables in my database: users, houses and user_choice.
I display data about houses like simple html table and for testing I display Id of each house like a number of house, which include a link, which user can click and go to other page to see more info about house.

I want to write in table each house in which user was interested. So, here is my logic: every time the user wants to know more about the house, he clicks on the link, after which my code should insert a record into the table "user_choice", which will contain the id of the user and the id of the house he chose. How can I do this?

My code:

```
<?php
include "db.php";
session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['Id_user']) && isset($_SESSION['Login'])) {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eu">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="card mt-5">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>Choose your house</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>№ house</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Area Type</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM house_rent_dataset";
                        $query_run = $mysqli->query($query);

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                        {
                            foreach($query_run as $row)
                            {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="about_house.php"><?= $row['Id_house']; ?></a></td>
                                    <td><?= $row['City']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row['Locality']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row['Area Type']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $row['Price']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">No Record Found</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    }
    else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: **How can i do**? -- just do it by an insert query

Comment: Simply add your query on the about_house.php file. You will need to pass the id of the house to that file.

Answer (score 2):

you can make simple logic with `count` on your click detail link of house that user choose.
Every user click link of detail it will going to new page that sent data param id of house, and display detail house.
You can make logic within your function that action is to display detail house with `updateOrCreate` (if you use php framework likes Laravel or CodeIgniter) to database `user_choice` with contain `user_id` and `house_id`.

Let me give an example

```
    // this is function for display detail of house that user //selected or click
    public function detailHouse(Request $request){

      //this is the code for make user_choice (recommended house     //for user based on user selected) 
      data["user_id"] = $request->user_id;
      data["house_id"] = $request->house_id;
      data["count"] += 1;
      user_choice::updateOrCreate(data);
      
      //this is your code for display detail of house selected
      $house = house::where('id', $request->house_id)->first()
      return view('detail_house', [
        'data' => $house
      ];
    }
```

Then, you can display table relation that display for user that recommended house for user based on how many user click or choose detail of every house